# I'm struggling with eclipse, error in appcompat

Tags: eclipse, macos, android-activity, android-appcompat

I'm new to android, the last few days I've been struggling with eclipse, sdk. My friend sent me a code and I want to run it in my mac computer. Please can you tell me what software I have to use and how. I'm struggling with app compat error. Please can you tell me the step by step process to run the code in eclipse, like which versions I have to use. Please help me.

Comment: How are we supposed to know without, at the bare minimum, looking at the code? Also, have you tried asking your friend?

Answer (score 0):

First of all go to the properties-android - and remove redcrossed appcompact library and just download appcompact library and import it in your worspace ;
then add it in your project. then refresh the project clean it and it will work